# Reference request : computation of homotopy groups of $\Sigma^k \mathbb{C}P^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology, reference-request

Would appreciate pointers to computations of the homotopy groups of $\Sigma^k \mathbb{C}P^n$ in the literature.

Comment: I imagine it is largely unknown. For the stable range, see [this](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82547916.pdf)

Comment: @ConnorMalin. Many thanks for the reference link.

Comment: Worth noting that in the opposite case, when $k = 0$, one has $\pi_t \mathbb{C}P^n = \pi_t S^{2n+1}$ for $t\geq 3$.

Comment: @nema. Yes, thank you.

Comment: Also the symmetric product of $n$ copies of $\mathbb{CP}^1$ is $\mathbb{CP}^n$ so the case $n=1$ is somehow dual to the case $k=0$